# Why is $g(JZ,JW)=-g(Z,W)$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a complex manifold, with Riemannian metric $g$ and complex
structure $J$. If $g$ satisfies
$$g(JX, JY ) = g(X, Y ),$$
for any two vector fields $X$ and $Y$.

I am reading a proof from [here, p.17](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~vando101/MRIlectures.pdf):
Holomorphic vector fields $Z$, by definition, satisfy $JZ = iZ$. We then find
$g(Z, W) = g(JZ, JW) = −g(Z, W)$, hence $g(Z, W) = 0$.

But $g(JZ, JW) = g(iZ, iW)=i(-i)g(Z,W)=g(Z,W)$, I wonder why does the proof get $g(Z, W) = g(JZ, JW) = −g(Z, W)$?

Comment: @mfl why not? I think it’s based on the formula of complex inner product

Comment: Why complex inner product? $g$ is riemannian, first of all.

Comment: @trying then why can we have $i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the author of these notes was not clear on which convention they were using for extending $g$ to complex tangent vectors. There are two competing conventions.

As in the notes you linked, we'll start off by assuming $g$ is a metric on the real tangent spaces $T_\mathbb{R}M$. The issue is that there are two ways to extend $g$ to be a metric on complex tangent vectors. One is just by extending $g$ to a $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear form on $T_\mathbb{R}M \otimes \mathbb{C}$, which I will just denote as $g$, and the other way is to extend it to a $\mathbb{C}$-sesquilinear form, which I will denote as $g_\mathbb{C}$. To contrast these, note that
$$
  g_\mathbb{C}(\lambda v, \mu w) = \lambda \bar{\mu}g_\mathbb{C}(v,w),
$$
while
$$
  g(\lambda v, \mu w) = \lambda \mu g(v,w)
$$
for complex numbers $\lambda,\mu$.

The author in your notes is claiming that two holomorphic vector fields $Z,W \in T^{1,0}\subset T_\mathbb{R}M\otimes \mathbb{C}$ are orthogonal with $g$, not with $g_\mathbb{C}$.

In fact, $g_\mathbb{C}$ restricted to holomorphic vector fields is a positive definite Hermitian metric in the usual sense. For a proof of this you can look in chapter 1.2 of Huybrechts' *Complex Geometry*. His book sticks to the sesquilinear convention.

On the other hand, the online text *Lectures on Kahler Geometry* by Moroianu makes the choice of extending $g$ bilinearly, and you might find the exposition there clearer. See section 5 in part 2 of those notes.

It seems that unless an author is very clear about which choice they are using, you have to check how $g$ behaves on holomorphic tangent vectors to see which convention is being used. Either $g(Z,Z) =0$ or $g(Z,Z)>0$ for a nonzero holomorphic tangent vector $Z$. The former means they are using the bilinear convention, and the latter means they are using the sesquilinear convention.